# Can't seem to set the tasks for Locust with Clarifai API

Tags: python, stress-testing, locust

aI am trying to use Locust to do stress testing for a model I made with Clarifai's API. I seem to have most of the stuff working but I can't seem to get the syntax of task assignment to work properly. The UI is working, the locust swarm works, I can get the stats in a csv but it isn't executing the task defined here which is the prediction being made to a custom model.

This is my function that is making the actual call.

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp, Workflow
import random
from locust import task, TaskSet, between, User

import app_settings. #contains some hardcoded values as a script. 
from locust_utils import ClarifaiLocust, locust_call
      

class ApiUser(ClarifaiLocust):
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 3000
    wait_time = between(2,5)

    def on_start(self):
        # self.small_model = self.client.get_app('model-specialization-demo-pt2').workflows.get('locust-vehicle-det')
        self.small_model = self.client.get_app('app_id').workflows.get('locust-vehicle-det')

    @task
    def predict_small_model(self):
        locust_call(
            self.small_model.predict_by_url,
            'predict to Public Vehicle Detector',
            url=random.choice(app_settings.small_app_urls)

        )
```

The functions being referred as ClarifaiLocust and locust_call are below

```
def locust_call(func, name, *args, **kwargs):
  start_time = time.time()
  try:
    func(*args, **kwargs)  # Don't really care about results for stress test
  except ApiError as e:
    total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
    events.request_failure.fire(
        request_type='Client', name=name, response_time=total_time, exception=e)
  else:
    total_time = int((time.time() - start_time) * 1000)
    events.request_success.fire(
        request_type='Client', name=name, response_time=total_time, response_length=0)


class ClarifaiLocust(HttpUser):
  test_app = None
  search_app = None
  wait_time = between(2,5)

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Locust.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    User.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    #super(ClarifaiLocust, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.client = ClarifaiUser(self.host)
```

but I keep getting this error.

```
raise Exception("No tasks defined. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User")
Exception: No tasks defined. use the @task decorator or set the tasks property of the User
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `abstract = True` on ClarifaiLocust, otherwise Locust will try to run it as well.

So:

```
class ClarifaiLocust(HttpUser):
    abstract = True
    ....
```

Comment: so would it say class ClarifaiLocust(HttpUser, abstract=True):

Comment: where would I add abstract =True?

Comment: It is a property on the class. Updated my answer.